# CO2 regulator dials

Tags: beer, carbonation, keg

I'm finally getting back into brewing. I'm using a keg my daughter bought me, and I have the CO2 tank.  At one point, I bought this regulator.  But the numbers on the dials don't seem to make any sense!  I've read about people using 8 .lbs of pressure, but if the red numbers are pounds, I can't even make it go that low without the adjustment screw coming all the way out.  Plus, if the black numbers are kilos, the conversion doesn't seem to make sense.  4 kg equal over 50 lbs?

I'm leaving it hooked up to the keg, but I'd really appreciate some help.  Thanks very much.

- Russ

[image: regulator dials]

Answer (score 1):

For the Top gauge this is your output pressure, adjusted by the screw

Numbers in red = PSI (marked bottom centre in red above the screws in the gauge)

Numbers in black = Kg/cm2 (marked bottom centre in black above the screws in the gauge) I think, picture not clear, but makes sense as 10Kg/cm2 = 142.233psi

so if you want 8psi it would be approx the first little red mark (7.5psi)

Here is an image of my setup, set to about 15psi serving pressure (bottle off)

At the end of the day you need to find what works for you, your setup and your beverage, the first little red tick mark is a good start point, if you get too much foam, then turn it down! if it does not come out quick enough, then turn it up! simples...

[image: Serving Pressure]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you would like to be at about 8 Lbs. for dispensing.It looks like the high and low pressure dials are oriented correctly, It could be that this assembly did not always have the check valve in place, and it had some beer accidentally backed into the works of the low pressure dial causing it to read incorrectly. A couple of questions though fist- Do all the dials drop to zero if you disconnect it from the tank? And did this regulator assembly work well before?